# Singular vs. plural in "Different {type / types} of {question / questions}"

Tags: grammatical-number

> Different types of questions

or

> Different type of questions

or

> Different types of question

or

> Different type of question.

Can anybody tell me, which one is the correct usage?

Comment: First one is the best of `em all.

Comment: "**The** first one. . ."

Answer (score 2):

I think they are all valid, depending on context.

> Different types of questions

"There are many different types of of questions in the examinations." This relates to the plurality of both words, there are many types of question in many examinations.

> Different type of questions

(I cannot think of an example for this version. All my attempts worked better without the "s" on "questions".)

> Different types of question

"The examination has many different types of question." This relates to the plurality of "examination", there is one examination in this case, but it has many questions.

```
Different type of question.
```

"To understand xxx requires a different type of question [than the one you are asking]." or "... [than those that you are asking].

Comment: Re. you second quote: "We have been asking yes-no for a while, now let's move on to a different type of questions: Open questions."

Comment: Thanks for the idea @Stephie but I would prefer "question" (singular) in that sentence. For all the example sentences I tried there, the singular form seemed best.